# updating plot output in shiny r

Tags: r, plot, shiny

For a Shiny app that I am working on, given a data file, I need to display a barplot (for which I am using ggplot2) on the starting page of the app. So when the user runs the app, and uploads a file, they would immediately get to see the barplot in main panel.

After the app has started, the user should be able to click an actionButton to bootstrap the data and add error bars to the same barplot. I don't want to add the error bars to start with, because my users might not be interested in the error bars and adding error bars with bootstrapping would keep them waiting. So, I must add the error bars only if they want to see it and are willing to wait for bootstrapping to be over.

I tried many ways to update the plot but haven't been successful. I could of course render another plot with the error bars but it is not what I would like to do ideally. Is there a way to update plots or add features to them?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example so we can build on it.

Comment: Thanks for your interest in the question. Someone else answered it in a way that solves my problem. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you always will have to go through `renderPlot` in order to update the plot output (unless you save the plot as a image, and load it on-top of your plot within an invisible div or something like this). What you could do is save the layers of your plot separately splitting it into 2 part, one with the bar plot and one with the error bar and then just layer the error bars on top if need be.

```
data(iris)
require(shiny)

sepal.length <- sapply(unique(iris$Species),function(s){ iris[which(iris$Species==s),"Sepal.Length"] })
data         <- data.frame("mean"=apply(sepal.length,2,mean),"sd"=apply(sepal.length,2,sd),"species"=unique(iris$Species))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # Save plot in reactive
  plot.dat <- reactiveValues(main=NULL, layer1=NULL)
  plot.dat$main <- ggplot(data=data,aes(x=species,y=mean,fill=species)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity") 

  observe({
    print("render")
    output$plot <- renderPlot({ plot.dat$main + plot.dat$layer1 })
  })

  observeEvent(input$add_bars,{
    # Calculate standard deviation
    plot.dat$layer1 <- geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd,ymax=mean+sd))
  })
})

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  plotOutput("plot"),
  actionButton("add_bars","Add error bars")
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks! that is what I was trying to do, split the plot in two parts, but I did not know how to do it properly in a Shiny context.

Comment: Hi again, while your answer helps, there is still something that I haven't been able to figure out. You defined the mean and sd in the global environment before you use them. However, I need to calculate the sd after event `input$add_bars` has been observed, and then attach it to the `data` before it gets used to add the layer with error bars. I haven't been successful in doing that. Can you help me with that? Thanks very much!

Comment: Actually I finally got it. I defined a new data frame in the event observer which had both the mean and sdev values and updated both the layers in the observer instead of updating just the layer with error bars. While this works, I am wondering if I might run into issues when users change the data file which they input. In any case, after a new file is input the layer with error bar from previous dataset stays leading to incorrect error bars for the new data file. It's more complicated than I imagined.

Comment: What you could do is setting `plot.dat$layer1` to NULL when you read in new data. Depending on your code, changing the datset migt or might not give you errors. If you can send me an example I'd be happy to take a quick look at it.

Comment: I thought about it. But the question is how to detect new file inputs. My file inputs work like it does in this demo: [link](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/upload-file.html).

Comment: You could always set `plot.dat$layer1`  to NULL before the `read.csv` call

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing this in shiny using **Plotly** but without layers as shown above. Although this may be an old thread, it may be helpful for others.

In the following example:

- first a plot is shown based on one person's scores.
- then as we select input from the list other scores of other persons are **updated on the same plot**.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput(
    inputId = "Player",
    selected = NULL,
    multiple = TRUE,
    label = " Choose Player",
    choices = c("Sam", "Bennet", "Orlando"),
    options = list('plugins' = list('remove_button'))
  ),
  plotlyOutput("Plot1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$Plot1 <-  renderPlotly({
    
    scores <- data.frame(Name = c("Sam", "Bennet", "Orlando", "Sam", "Bennet", "Orlando", "Sam", "Bennet", "Orlando" ), 
                        Number= c(47, 35, 40, 49, 32, 31, 51, 49, 44 ),
                        Year = c("2018","2018","2018", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2016","2016","2016")
    )  
    
    chris_goals <- data.frame(Name = c("Chris", "Chris", "Chris"), 
                        Number= c(90, 95, 100 ),
                        Year = c("2018","2017","2016")
    ) 
    
    filteredScores <- reactive({
      
      plot_ly(chris_goals, x = ~Year, y = ~Number, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', color = ~Name)%>% layout(showlegend = TRUE) %>%
        layout(title = 'Scores') %>%
        add_trace(data =  scores[scores$Name %in% input$Player, ], x = ~Year, y = ~Number, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', color = ~Name)
    })
    
    filteredScores()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Default:
[image]

[image]